# Moving a window to another workspace works only when at least 2 apps are open - why?

Tags: applications, keyboard-shortcuts, workspace

I noticed that I am not able to move apps' windows to the next workspace if there is just 1 app running in my current workspace.
It's not a big issue, since, normally I'd want to move apps to another workspace only if it is cluttered with too many apps.
However, sometimes I just know that I want to launch 3 apps, and each one will be in its own space. I launch the first app, I try to move it to far right workspace, because that's where I want this app to reside. I can't, because it's the only app I have currently, and OS will not allow me to move it yet. I need to open another app first. That slows me down a bit.

Comment: It's a design decision to automatically clear any empty workspaces, and afaik, there's no way to change that. You can install the [Workspaces](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.devalien.workspaces/) app that will let you open multiple predefined apps at once, and then you can organize them as you wish to.

Comment: I like automatic workspaces deletion, it's convenient. However, I think I should be able to open a new one anytime.